# Filter entries in NextJS by two queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Hello everyone I have a project on NextJS. There is a portfolio of works that is generated from json.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Плагин WordPress для Рекомендательного виджета Яндекса",
        "image": "/images/works/yk.jpg",
        "year": 2022,
        "category": "WordPress",
        "link": "https://188.ru/",
        "description": "Заказчик использует на некоторых сайтах виджет рекомендаций от Яндекса, который позволяет показывать ссылки на статьи сайта вместе с рекламой Яндекса. Проблема в том, что система от отечественного поисковика не очень умная и тянет в виджет не только статьи, но и много чего не нужного. Я написал микроплагин, который дает возможность автоматически проставлять специальный тег на страницах, которые не нужно показывать в виджете, а также позволяет исключать некоторые статьи из виджета вручную"
    },
    {
        "title": "Сайт студии переводов «АкадемПеревод»",
        "image": "/images/works/ap.jpg",
        "year": 2022,
        "category": "WordPress",
        "link": "https://academperevod.ru/",
        "description": "Осовременивали сайт, не перезжая с Wordpress на другие платформы. В основе проекта - дизайн в Фигме и редактор Elementor. Сложная, долгая и кропотливая работа",
        "scroll": true
    }
]
```

I decided to filter the elements by category, which is specified by json.
Here is my component that displays a list of categories and adds filtering on the page above the list of all portfolio works:

```
//filter-work.js

import works from "@/content/works/data.json"


export default function FilterWork({selectedCat, onSelect}) {

    const splitCats = works.flatMap((w) => w.category.split());
    const categories = Array.from(new Set(splitCats));


    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li
                    className={!selectedCat ? "bg-indigo-50 p-2 rounded-md" : "p-2"}
                    onClick={() => onSelect("")}
                >
                    <a>Все</a>
                </li>
                {categories.map((category, i) => {
                    const isSelected = category === selectedCat
                    return (
                        <li key={i} item={category}
                            className={isSelected ? "bg-indigo-50 p-2 rounded-md" : "p-2"}
                            onClick={() => onSelect(category)}
                        >
                            {category}
                        </li>
                    )


                    })}
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}
```

And here is the code of the page that displays both a list of all the works and a list of categories in the filter. My main filter code is also here.

```
import { useState } from "react"
import Seo from "@/components/global/seo";
import Work from "../components/work";
import {getAllWork} from "@/lib/getAllData";
import styles from "@/styles/home/featuredWork.module.css"

import FilterWork from "@/components/filter-work";

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const work = getAllWork();

    return {
        props: {
            work,
        },
    };
}

export default function WorkPage({work}) {

     const [selectedCat, setSelectedCat] = useState("");

    const filteredCat = selectedCat ? work.filter((listItem) => listItem.category.includes(selectedCat))
    : work;

    return (
        <div>
            <Seo
                title="Все работы Колтан Леонида"
                description="Здесь собраны некоторые из работ разработчика Колтан Леонида"
                ogImageUrl={`http://localhost:3000/api/og?title=Все работы Колтан Леонида&description=Здесь собраны некоторые из работ разработчика Колтан Леонида`}
            />
            <section className='px-6'>
                <div className='wrapper'>
                    <h1 className='sectionTitle'>Проекты</h1>
                    <FilterWork
                        selectedCat={selectedCat}
                        onSelect={setSelectedCat}
                    />
                    <div className={styles.featuredWorkInner}>
                        {filteredCat.map((workItem) => (
                            <Work key={workItem.title} item={workItem} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The filter works, here it is on the test domain - https://next-site-ivory-six.vercel.app/work . The question is that I would like to add another filter by year, which is also specified in the json file. I tried to do something like this:

```
    const filteredCat = selectedCat ? work.filter((listItem) => listItem.category.includes(selectedCat)) && work.filter((listItem) => listItem.year.toString().includes(selectedCat)): work;
```

But nothing works like that. It is filtered either by categories or by years depending on the operator that I will specify in the code above (`&&` or `||`), and I need there to be mutual filtering - that is, if I chose `Wordpress` and `2022`, so that only works with the `Wordpress` category with the year `2022` are displayed. How to do it?

And can you tell me how to output some message if no element is shown? For example, "Nothing found. Select other filters"

Comment: __listItem.year.toString().includes(selectedCat)__?? How can category be year?? Did you added another state for year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple filters you need to define your filter function as follows

```
const filteredWork = work.filter(w => {
   const catFilter = selectedCat ? w.category === selectedCat : true; // true if no category selected
   const yearFilter = selectedYear ? w.year === selectedYear : true; // true if no year selected
   return catFilter && yearFilter;
})
```

As per the comment below, either have selectedYear as number or use `==` in place of `===`.

Comment: Also as the year is integer is the sample data, either save selectedYear as integer state or convert to the correct type while comparing w.year === selectedYear

Comment: And can you tell me how to output some message if no element is shown? For example, "Nothing found. Select other filters"

Comment: If filteredWork.length == 0 -> show message

Answer (score 0):

```js
const work = [{
    "title": "Плагин WordPress для Рекомендательного виджета Яндекса",
    "image": "/images/works/yk.jpg",
    "year": 2022,
    "category": "WordPress",
    "link": "https://188.ru/",
    "description": "Заказчик использует на некоторых сайтах виджет рекомендаций от Яндекса, который позволяет показывать ссылки на статьи сайта вместе с рекламой Яндекса. Проблема в том, что система от отечественного поисковика не очень умная и тянет в виджет не только статьи, но и много чего не нужного. Я написал микроплагин, который дает возможность автоматически проставлять специальный тег на страницах, которые не нужно показывать в виджете, а также позволяет исключать некоторые статьи из виджета вручную"
  },
  {
    "title": "Сайт студии переводов «АкадемПеревод»",
    "image": "/images/works/ap.jpg",
    "year": 2022,
    "category": "WordPress",
    "link": "https://academperevod.ru/",
    "description": "Осовременивали сайт, не перезжая с Wordpress на другие платформы. В основе проекта - дизайн в Фигме и редактор Elementor. Сложная, долгая и кропотливая работа",
    "scroll": true
  }
];

const selected = {
  cat: "otherCat",
  year: "2021"
};

document.getElementById("year").addEventListener("change", e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  selected.year = e.target.value;
  printFiltered();
});

document.getElementById("cat").addEventListener("change", e => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  selected.cat = e.target.value;
  printFiltered();
});

function printFiltered() {
  const filteredWork = work.filter(w => {
    const catFilter = selected.cat ? w.category === selected.cat : true; // true if no category selected
    const yearFilter = selected.year ? w.year == selected.year : true; // true if no year selected
    return catFilter && yearFilter;
  })

  console.log(filteredWork);
}
```

```html
<select id="year">
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
</select>

<select id="cat">
  <option value="otherCat">otherCat</option>
  <option value="WordPress">WordPress</option>
</select>

<p id="result" />
```

Note that I am using `==` instead of using parseInt for year.